# Is it possible to work out exactly when a domain will be transferred?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-transferring

I know there are expiry times for the dns records. But what are they called? Where re they stored? Are they different for each country?

Comment: You seem to be conflating at least 2 concepts (DNS TTL and Registrar Transfers). Which are you asking about?  Please rewrite your question to be clear and specific.

Comment: Well, during a transfer the dns is updated. So it's related?

Comment: @RD. Are you referring to transferring to a new registrar?  A registrar transfer can be done without changing name servers or zone files.  Please give specific details regarding the situation you're trying to resolve.

Comment: I mean, that the nameservers of doamin ABC.com is set to ns1.ABC.com and ns1.ABC.com .... .(abc being  sample domain). I update it to ns1.newdomain.com and ns2.newdomain.com. What time will it take propogate. Exactly.......

Comment: For 5 your questions you have 4 with answers, but accept only one and doesn't show intersest in others. It seems as you don't want good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Expire time and TTL is slightly different topics in hostmaster's world.
2. You asked about TTL. TTL (TimeToLive) define (as name states), how long **properly** configured 3-party DNS-server will store received information in own cache, answer to clients  with  this data and will not forward request to external world.
3. TTL linked with every RR in zone and stored in file (or other source) with zone definition.
   Default TTL defined in SOA RR and apply to all data without RR-specific TTL inside  zone
4. Your this question poorly related with "domain-transferring" tag